# Positioning labels on x axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a simple graph, x and y coordinates, however how my axis labels are not quite as I wish.

- How can I change the '1e+08' and so on to their true value, 100000000
- How can I shift the labels of the xtics down so they don't obscure the graph?
- Can I print the coordinates in the graph of certian points, for example the dip between 2014-05-10-04-00 and 2014-05-10-08-00?
- How can one add more intervals in the labels of the x axis?

Here is the input I'm using:

```
reset
clear
set output "BytesOverTime.png"
set title "Evolution of Bytes over Time"
set ylabel 'Bytes'
set xlabel 'Time'
set key off
set term png
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"
set xtics rotate by 90 nomirror
set datafile separator ' '
set logscale y
plot "timeBytesAverage.out" using 1:2
```

And the file if its needed to test:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qqpeJj4V

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change the '1e+08' and so on to their true value, 100000000

```
set format y "%f"
```

or, as this will give you decimal numbers:

```
set format y "%.0f"
```

You may also have a look at

```
set format y "%.0s%cByte"
```

which will create MByte, GByte, ... (See right y-axis in my plot)
However, this will be to the base of 1000, not 1024.

> How can I shift the labels of the xtics down so they don't obscure the graph?

```
set xtics rotate by 90 nomirror right
```

will right-align (left-flush) the tic marks

> Can I print the coordinates in the graph of certian points, for example the dip between 2014-05-10-04-00 and 2014-05-10-08-00?

If you know the coordinates, yes:

```
set xtics add ("high" "2014-05-09-23-30", "low" "2014-05-10-22-30" )
```

The general syntax is:

```
set xtics add (  <label1> <position1>, <label2> <position2> , ...)
```

This will add the list of labels to the automatically generated labels. If you omit the word `add`, there will be no automatically generated labels, just those in your list.

> How can one add more intervals in the labels of the x axis?

```
set xtics 3600
```

will generate a label every 3600 seconds, i.e. every hour. This does not work for log scale axes.

```
set mxtics 2
```

will cause the gap between two major (labeled) tics being divided into two smaller gaps, i.e. one minor tic mark between two major ones. (However, it seems not to be necessary here, as gnuplot decides to use 2 on it's own)

And here is the result:

[image]

Note that I also added

```
set y2tics
set y2range[1E8:1E12]
set format y2 "%.0s%cByte"
set logscale y2
```

to demonstrate this special format on the right y-axis.

And by the way: The format of the labels on the y-axis is independent from the format in the data file.

`set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"` defines the format inside the file

`set format x "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M` defines the format in the plot. So ou may do something like `set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` which is more readable.